# Reading portion of CSV with multiple data types

Tags: matlab, csv

I have a csv file with both numbers and letters that I want to read. The file also has headers(first row) but I can read them separately so that's not a concern.
What I can't solve is the fact that the file has multiple data types and that I only want to read a portion(since the file is very large), say the first 5000 rows.

I've tried xlsread  with three outputs but I get the following error : "??? Error: Object returned error code: 0x800A03EC". I've also tried textscan but if I understood correctly you've to type the variable types as an input and that's not very practical for me since I have a large amount of columns. I hope this is not a duplicate but I've read other solutions and I could not apply them to my problem.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is excel installed on the system? If so, can you open the file in excel manually? `xlsread` tries to use the excel com interface.

Comment: I've it installed but the file is so big that it's not easy. Once I have it open what do you suggest I do? I've tried pasting the data as a new variable but I get an error.

Answer (score 1):

To test the problem i created a small test.csv file.
It contains the following lines:

```
header1;header2;header3
a;1;xx
b;2;yy
c;3;zz
d;4;xxx
e;5;yyy
```

I use the following code to read the data:

```
range = 'A2:C3'
[num, text, both] = xlsread('test.csv', 1, range)
```

Output of the both variable, that contains the text and numbers, is as expected:

```
both = 

    'a'    [1]    'xx'
    'b'    [2]    'yy'
```

Comment: I had tried that before and I did again but I get error :
??? Error: Object returned error code: 0x800A03EC

Error in ==> xlsread at 250
    ExcelWorkbook = Excel.workbooks.Open(file,0,true);

Maybe it's related to the fact that in the same column I may have more than one data type?

Comment: I can have strings and numbers in one column- just checked it.  Have you tried to load my test.csv example? Do you have the same problems with that file?

Comment: yes, I have and it works. However, when I use the code above on my file I get an error.
There are
several possible reasons:

• The file name or path does not exist.
• The file is being used by another program.
• The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a
currently open workbook.
Help File: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
Office\Office12\1033\XLMAIN11.CHM
Help Context ID: 0

Error in ==> xlsread at 250
    ExcelWorkbook = Excel.workbooks.Open(file,0,true);


I don't think the file is being used elsewhere and it exists, since I extract headers from it and open it on excel.

Comment: You could try to copy the first 10/100/1000 rows and columns of your large csv file into a smaller one and check if you can read the smaller ones without errors.